# Project dependency jar not downloaded in maven repository after version updation

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management, rad

I have jar dependency of other project inside my project.

When I update the version no from 1.0.52 to 1.0.118 as below,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
        <artifactId>pf-schema-v3</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.52</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
        <artifactId>pf-schema-v3</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.118</version>
    </dependency>
```

The updated jar is not getting available in maven local repository.
pf-schema-v3-1.0.118 is already available in central repository, it should get downloaded in the local repository.
Due to which the dependency issue is coming in RAD.
I checked in the target folder of the project, its updating the jar there.

**Thanks for the answers, the problem got resolved now.**

Comment: post the `groupId:artifactId:version` info

Comment: It's another maven project dependency. of which jar is available on my central repository.

Comment: goto that project and do `mvn clean install` come back to this project and do `mvn clean install`

Comment: The is already build and its jar is available in central repository to which my application is pointing.

Comment: run ```mvn install -e``` and update your question with the exception.

Comment: But the build is successful. How, would -e option will give any error?

Comment: Sorry, I had two repositories. Didn't knew that it was getting downloaded in the other repository. Issue got solved by pointing M2_REPO variable to the path of that repository.

Comment: ok feel free to add it as an answer and accept your answer for others reference

Answer (score 0):

First run maven-install for the projects 'pf-schema-v3' and check if gets added to the repository.Do not run maven-build as it will only produce a binary and it will not add anything to the repository.
If you are using eclipse also check that if the project properties is set to use the 'pf-schema-v3'
as a dependency.

Comment: pf-schema-v3 is already in the central repository. I don't understand why the mvn install is required on that project. As, if i do that, it will not store the dependency in local repository. But, it will be project local jar. I don't want to manually copy it in the local repository folder.

Answer (score 0):

1. first run mvn install on your project.maven  will install all the latest dependencies to your local repository.
2. check your local repository pf-schema-v3 latest jar avilable or not. if still not downloaded you need to install the jar manually using mvn command.

here is the comand example:mvn install:install-file  -DgroupId=javax.transaction -DartifactId=jta   -Dpackaging=jar   -Dversion=1.0.1B   -Dfile=jta-1.0.1B.jar   -DgeneratePom=true

Answer (score 0):

I had two repositories. The pf-schema-v3-1.0.118 was getting downloaded in the latest repository.
My RAD M2_REPO library was still pointing to the old repository path.
Issue got solved by pointing M2_REPO variable to the path of that repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can initiate below command to make sure that the dependencies are forced to download again from central repo to your local repository.

cmd : mvn clean install -U